# CSS floating div taking remaining width

Tags: css

I can't seem to make this work and am considering using table for that now.

I have a page with 3 main divs that are all on the same line (floats).
I want the div in the middle (#pages) to take the remaining width since I can toggle() both of the sides divs.

It looks like that :

[image]

jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/5n3rz/

Here's my code :

```
<div id="project">
      <ul>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>z</li>
        <li>z</li>    
      </ul>
</div>

<div class="minus">
    <a href="#" class="close close_project">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
      </a>
</div>

<div id="pages">
      <textarea name="text" id="texta-pages" placeholder="your page"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="minus">
      <a href="#" class="close close_notes">
        <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
      </a>
</div>

<div id="notes">
      <textarea name="notes" id="texta-notes" placeholder="your notes"></textarea>
</div>
```

and here's my current CSS :

everything is height:100%

```
#project, .minus, #pages, #notes{
 height:100%;
 float:left;
}
#project{
 width:150px;
}
.minus{
 background-color:#CCC;
 width:20px;
}
#pages{
 min-width:calc((100% - 2*20px - 150px)/2);
}
#notes{
 width:calc((100% - 2*20px - 150px)/2);
}
```

I use jQuery to toggle() the project on the left, and the notes on the right.
I want the #pages part to take all the remaining width when I remove one or both divs on its side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CSS tables to do this.

---

**EDIT:**
So this is what you need to modify to get it to work:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5n3rz/2/)**

```
main{
    height:90%;
    display: table; /* added */
    table-layout: fixed; /* added */
    width: 100%; /* added */
}
#project, .minus, #pages, #notes{
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell; /* added; removed float:left */
}

#project{
    width:50%; /* modified width */
}

#pages{
    width: 100%; /* modified width */
}
#notes{
    width:50%; /* modified width */
}
```

---

Here is a (simplified) example:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/tySH8/)**

In this example you can verify that when you delete column one or three (or both) - the middle column fills up the remaining space. (right click inspect element and then select 'delete node' to remove col1 or col3)

The trick here is to give col2 a value of `width:100%`

### Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col col1">div1</div>
    <div class="col col2">div2</div>
    <div class="col col3">div3</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container
{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.col
{
    display: table-cell;    
}

.col1
{
    background: pink;
    width: 20%;
}
.col2
{
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
}
.col3
{
    background: brown;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: in the fiddle you provided, the #project div doesn't display correctly. The ul is at the bottom of the div. And when I try to do it in my code as well I have the textareas that display at the bottom of their divs as well. I think you miss a div: display:table-row before the table-cell

Comment: Not sure I understand you, but in any case try adding vertical-align: top; to the divs with display:table-cell

Comment: the vertical-align works! I wonder why it doesn't work without.

Comment: the initial/default value for vertical-align is baseline - this is generally not what you want when using css tables

Answer (score 1):

Don't float `#page` left and give it the `overflow:hidden` property:

```
#project, .minus, #notes {
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

#pages {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

If a block element is on the same line as floated elements you can set the overflow style to hidden and it will take up the rest of the available width of its parent.

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jxp8Q/)

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn't work (I guess too many divs). I edited the page and added a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5n3rz/